# Trying to apply navigation through highlighted results after search similar to Ctrl + F

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a chat similar to WhatsApp Web and I'm applying a search similar to the Ctrl + F. I have an input that take the `searchQuery` and pass it to a component I call `TextFormatter`. I'm trying to count the quantity of highlighted text to apply a navigation through them using arrows icons on my input. The main problem is that if I put a `console.log("hi")` on both components when I count the quantity, it displays normal and the correct number of times, but when I set the state manipulation it increases indefinitely, doing my page crash. Both  `setTotalOfResults((prevTotal) => prevTotal + 1);` or `setTotalOfResults(totalOfResults + 1);` don't work. As I said, my idea is to get that number to know how many highlighted results are and navigate through it index. Another problem is that I have `const parts = text.normalize("NFD").replace(accentsRegex, "").split(regex);` but it removes accents from the highlighted text, and if I remove the replace, it gets the whole sentence and not only what I want. For example, consider content between `()` is highlighted:

```
searchQuery = "Café";
sentence = "Hello, café! I'm testing accents.";

//With replace:
"Hello, (cafe)! I'm testing accents.";

//Without replace:
"(Hello, café! I'm testing accents.)";
```

Thanks in advance for reading until here!

Chat.tsx

```
//...
function Chat (props: ChatProps) {
//...

const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [totalOfResults, setTotalOfResults] = useState<number>(0);
const [selectedResultIndex, setSelectedResultIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);

//...

const handleSearchBarChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const searchQuery = event.target.value;
    setSearch(searchQuery);
    setTotalOfResults(0);
    setSelectedResultIndex(null);
  };
}

const handleMatchesCounterChange = () => {
    /* setTotalOfResults((prevTotal) => prevTotal + 1); */
    console.log("hi");
  };

//...

return (
<div className="chat">
  <div className="chat-header">
    //...
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search..."
      value={search}
      onChange={handleSearchBarChange}
      className={`search-input ${isSearchBarVisible ? "active" : ""}`}
      ref={inputRef}
    />
  </div>

  //...
  <div className="chat-content" ref={chatContentRef}>
  //...
    {props.chatData.map((message) => (
  //...
       <div className="message-content">
         <TextFormatter
          text={message.content}
          searchQuery={search}
          onMatchesCounterChange={handleMatchesCounterChange}
          selectedResultIndex={selectedResultIndex}
       />
       </div>
       <div className="message-bottom">
         <div className="message-timestamp">
           <span>{formatTimestamp(message.created_at)}</span>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    ))}
 </div>
 //...

</div>
)
```

TextFormatter.tsx

````
/* import { useEffect, useState } from "react"; */
import "./textFormatter.css";

interface TextFormatterProps {
  text: string;
  searchQuery?: string | null;
  selectedResultIndex?: number | null;
  onMatchesCounterChange?: () => void;
}

function TextFormatter(props: TextFormatterProps) {
  const boldRegex = /\*([^\s*].*?[^\s*])\*/g;
  const italicRegex = /\_([^\s_].*?[^\s_])\_/g;
  const strikeRegex = /\~([^\s~].*?[^\s~])\~/g;
  const monospaceRegex = /\```([^```].*?[^```])\```/gs;

  const formattingRegex = /(\*[^*]+\*|_[^_]+_|~[^~]+~|```[^```]+```)/g;

  const formatText = (text: string) => {
    let formattedText = text.split(formattingRegex);

    return formattedText;
  };

  const formattedText = formatText(props.text);

  const highlightText = (text: string) => {
    if (!props.searchQuery || props.searchQuery.trim() === "") {
      return text;
    }

    const accentsRegex = /[\u0300-\u036f]/gi;

    const formattedSearchQuery = props.searchQuery
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(accentsRegex, "")
      .toLowerCase();

    const regex = new RegExp(`(${formattedSearchQuery})`, "gi");
    const parts = text.normalize("NFD").replace(accentsRegex, "").split(regex);

    const incrementMatchesCounter = () => {
      if (props.onMatchesCounterChange) {
        props.onMatchesCounterChange();
        console.log("hi");
      }
    };

    return parts.map((part, index) => {
      if (
        regex.test(
          part.normalize("NFD").replace(accentsRegex, "").toLowerCase()
        )
      ) {
        incrementMatchesCounter();
        return (
          <span
            key={index}
            className={`highlight ${
              props.selectedResultIndex && props.selectedResultIndex === index
                ? "selected-highlight"
                : ""
            }`}
          >
            {part}
          </span>
        );
      }
      return part;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="copyable-text">
      {formattedText.map((segment, index) => {
        if (boldRegex.test(segment)) {
          return (
            <span key={index} className="bold">
              {highlightText(segment.replace(boldRegex, "$1"))}
            </span>
          );
        } else if (italicRegex.test(segment)) {
          return (
            <span key={index} className="italic">
              {highlightText(segment.replace(italicRegex, "$1"))}
            </span>
          );
        } else if (strikeRegex.test(segment)) {
          return (
            <span key={index} className="strike">
              {highlightText(segment.replace(strikeRegex, "$1"))}
            </span>
          );
        } else if (monospaceRegex.test(segment)) {
          return (
            <span key={index} className="monospace">
              {highlightText(segment.replace(monospaceRegex, "$1"))}
            </span>
          );
        } else {
          return highlightText(segment);
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextFormatter;
````

I tried to change the manipulation of the counter state, but it didn't work. I also tried to count it inside my `TextFormatter` and pass it to my `Chat`, but it gave me the minified error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `incrementMatchesCounter` is executed on every render. It's like using code like this:

```js
function Component() {
   const [state, setState] = useState(0);

   state(state => state + 1);
}
```

which is an infinite loop. You need to refactor your code and change the sate only when the `prop.text` and `prop.formattedSearchQuery` are changing. You can use useEffect for this.

But also note that you don't need to use state for the number of matches. You already have a state in the form of a `text` and `formattedSearchQuery`.

Comment: Oh, I see!  Thank you very much!  I was stuck on this.